# Ошибка в количестве нейронов

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Код:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

dataset = np.loadtxt(r'C:/Users/Dima/Desktop/data.txt', delimiter=",")
# Первые 8 столбцов данные, последний столб - класс. 
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
#binary_crossentropy - т.к. у нас два класса.
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=15, batch_size=10,  verbose=1)
predictions = model.predict(X)
```

и сообщения об ошибках:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2534a5ce5f7a> in <module>()
     18 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
     19 
---> 20 model.fit(X, Y, epochs=15, batch_size=10,  verbose=1)
     21 # Предсказание
     22 predictions = model.predict(X)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    961                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
    962                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
--> 963                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
    964 
    965     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1628             sample_weight=sample_weight,
   1629             class_weight=class_weight,
-> 1630             batch_size=batch_size)
   1631         # Prepare validation data.
   1632         do_validation = False

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
   1478                                     output_shapes,
   1479                                     check_batch_axis=False,
-> 1480                                     exception_prefix='target')
   1481         sample_weights = _standardize_sample_weights(sample_weight,
   1482                                                      self._feed_output_names)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    121                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    122                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 123                             str(data_shape))
    124     return data
    125 
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_12 to have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В случае бинарной классификации (два класса) в последнем слое нейронной сети нужен всего один нейрон и функция активации `'sigmoid'`:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))    # output layer
#binary_crossentropy - т.к. у нас два класса.
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=15, batch_size=10,  verbose=1)
predictions = model.predict(X)
```

PS в случае мультиклассовой классификации (`categorical_crossentropy`) число нейронов в последнем / выходном слое должно соответствовать числу классов.

Comment: Спасибо большое! :)

Comment: @HelloGoogle, был рад помочь :)